# Getting get parameters from traditional way in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using wire2air for sending and receiving the messages.

Here is the documentation link:
https://www.wire2air.com/docs/http-api/receive-sms-httpapi/

In their callback url they have instructions to type the url like this.

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/textme.php?
```

**but i have setup like this**

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/textme?
```

however from their documentation, it appears these send back the variables in the GET variable format.

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/textme?
MobileNumber=xxxxxxxx&Message=xxxxxxx&Rcvd=1-2-2015 02:18:30&shortcode=xxxx
```

is it true for laravel too. would i get back url in the same format in laravel too? how would laravel pick that url?

in my route it is setup like

```
Route::get('textme', 'Wire2AirController@send_this_info');
```

In my Wire2AirController i am trying to retrive those variables in this format:

```
    $message = Input::get('Message');
    $mobile =  Input::get('MobileNumber');
```

but i am unable to catch them, i am not sure if they will send the variables like this format in laravel too. if they sending then for some reason laravel never picks these up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input facade is depreciated. You should use request helper or Request service provider or Request facade instead.

You should be able to catch these params either by using request helper as @bryceandy said or just by using a Request service provider as shown below:

```
public function receive (Request $request)
{
    // Option 1
    $message = $request->query('Message');
    $mobile = $request->query('MobileNumber');

    // Option 2
    $params = $request->query(); // returns an array with all received params

    // Option 3
    $message = $request->input('Message');
    $mobile = $request->input('MobileNumber');

   // Option 4
   $message = Request::input('Message');
   $mobile = Request::input('MobileNumber');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the request helper instead of input and if they are sent correctly you will obtain them

```
$message = request('Message');
$mobile = request('Mobile');
```